# Under what scenario will a hacker get the table but not the PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, security, salt

Ok, so I understand the value of the salt in my hashed passwords... kind of.

I am setting up a basic authentication scheme where I am setting passwords and users don't have the ability to set the passwords as something that they might use for another site.

So what is the real utility of the salt?

Under what circumstances could someone compromise my user table but not also get access to the rest of the tables with all the data, or my PHP code that shows the magic?

I'm trying to determine whether use of a salt is really that important in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Salt is important if you want your users to not be *massively* affected if/when your password table is stolen (they will be affected anyway in the sense that in this scenario, you should force an immediate password change for everyone to limit the damage as much as possible). Why do you care how the accident might happen? Would you ask under what conditions an airbag would activate and think about *not* installing one in your car?

Comment: Perhaps you should choose a different answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted that SQL Injection can be used to read files using [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  By having a salt value unknown to the attacker,  this will force the attacker into making a lot more guesses in order to obtain the plain text.  Although salting almost never takes this into consideration.  The main idea is two accomplish two things:

1) Two users with the same password will have different password hashes.  This is why some salting systems using very small salts,  such as only a few bytes.

2) Forcing the attacker to generate larger [rainbow tables](http://project-rainbowcrack.com/).  In this case you want at least 8 bytes.  Often times you see salts the same number of bits as the message digest function which makes pre-computation totally infeasible.

Once the salt is obtained a tool [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) can be used to brute force the password.  GPU's are also commonly used to break heavily salted passwords.   It should be noted that bcrypt() good at defending against FPGA's and GPU's due to its high memory requirements.  [Using memory hard functions for password storage](http://www.bsdcan.org/2009/schedule/attachments/87_scrypt.pdf) can yield a very strong password storage system.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, the salt slows down the reverse calculation of user passwords in the event of that table being compromised.  Salts are concatednated to a password and then unidirectionally hashed to avoid the ability of compromised passwords to be determined from Rainbow Tables, or lists of pre-hashed passwords.

Comment: So I guess the question then is, what is the consequence of the passwords being reversely calculated after the site has been compromised. In my case, nothing; the security hole needs to be fixed and the passwords need the be re-generated, but someone having the 10-15 passwords I made up isn't going to do them any good once I identify and fix the problem, right? So no salt?

Answer (score -1):

If you salt with lets say one ASCII char randomly, the attacker needs a table which size is  256 times greater relativly to a rainbow table without salts.

For 2 ASCII char salt its already 65536 times more size.

What really needs to be mentioned, why you should use salts at all is the fact that most users use words directly found in a dictionary. I have no data on how much, but I guess it is much. So even if there are no rainbow tables used, an attacker can only "bruteforce" a small set of passwords at a single time. If you have no salt, do a dictionary attack with some modifications (addings numbers,...) and you get lets say 30% of all passwords with only one dictionary attack. With a salt this cannot happen in one run, means it takes much more time, means its pointless for an attacker.

For your other question:

nothing hinders an attacker to get your other table data. But thats nothing hashed passwords with or without a salt can avoid.

Comment: You are probably talking about md5, you can also hash with sha256 etc, it is very hard to find original string if it's not 123456 type...

Comment: makes no difference to what I said. Furthermore, today I'm happy if the application uses hashes at all. If salted even better. Fact is there are millions of applications which don't even use any kind of hash. So sha256 is not the criteria why not using salts. Anyway even with sha256 you are safer using a salt, thats a fact. The data has to be safe for years, who knows if an evil bastard is already calculation it? :)

Comment: It's not evil, it's smart... Of course passwords should be salted, I was just saying that pure md5 is easiest to crack... every non standard hash/encryption is good... You can't crack it if you don't know what it is.

Comment: you mean security by obscurity? I would never use any encryption/hashing algorithm which is not public available and checked by cryptographers.

Comment: -1 65536 rainbow tables?  NO sir,  a 2 char salt is worthless and should already be covered by a moderately sized rainbow table.   You should at least read about "rainbowcrack" before telling other people how it works.

Comment: sorry, what I mean is the size of the rainbow table grows that much relativly to no salts.

Answer (score -1):

The big issue with salting passwords (and hashing them in the first place), is because a lot of people... in fact almost all people... re-use their passwords. Furthermore, most user-tables also store emails and/or usernames. So if someone manages to get the password of all your users, the damage hasn't just been done on your site, but also anywhere else that those users are signed up where they can easily be looked up. With all the data that normally is stored in usertables, the damage is hard to exaggerate.

In short; cracked passwords not only give users access to the things *you* are hosting, but affects the customers' security on just about every site they log on to.

But to answer the title question; it's extremely likely that if your database is compromised, that your PHP code is as well. However, they might only get read-access to your PHP code, whereas most database access levels do require INSERT/UPDATE access for the app to function at all. Some people split SQL access to read and write, but that really isn't realistic in most cases because you're always INSERTing and UPDATEing, even in pages where your users haven't even logged in (counters, like/unlike buttons, etc.).

Comment: So... can anyone shed light on how I may improve my understanding, seeing the -1?